# Como combinar dois vetores e obter todos resultados de uma determinada conta com eles

Tags: r, if, rnorm

Estou tentando realizar um cálculo e necessito da ajuda de vocês. Primeiro eu faço uma sequência com distribuição normal com 420 números, depois eu faço uma sequência de números que chamo de `mci` com 42 números, depois o próximo cálculo tem uma condição `if`.

Nesta parte eu preciso que na minha condição sempre compare a primeira lista de vetor do `mci` com o primeiro número dos valores que gerei da minha distribuição normal, depois todo o processo se repita com o segundo numero até completar os 420.

Por exemplo: Para rp = (28, 27, 26...),  bwg = (conta com mci[i]) > rp

Quero que esse `rp` seja sempre o 28 até acabar a primeira sequencia de 42 numeros, e depois comparar com 27 da segunda sequencia do meu vetor. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que a condição sempre compara sempre o mesmo valor de `rp`, e acho que o R não está fazendo isso, comparando por exemplo o valor 26,912 com 0,435 onde ele deveria comparar com o 0,429

```
max <- 30
K <- 0.0118
Xm <- 21
SD <- 0.851636356306513 
mean.b <- 28

rp <- rnorm(420, mean = mean.b, sd = SD)
BW <- 0.0223*rp^0.8944 
mci <- seq(200, 270, 1.7)
bwg <- ifelse((max*(1-exp(-K*(MCi-(BW*Xm))))) > rp, yes = rp, no = (max*(1-exp(-K*(MCi-(BW*Xm))))))
```

Comment: DownVote até você editar o título da pergunta.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow! Primeiramente, não use caps lock no título da sua pergunta, segundo, esclareça com mínimas palavras o que quer fazer no título da pergunta, terceiro, deixe claro onde está o problema, o que está tentando fazer e o que ocorreu de errado.

Comment: Veja  [como criar um exemplo Mínimo, 
Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se eu entendi bem o seu problema, você quer calcular a expressão `bwg <- (max*(1-exp(-K*(MCi-(BW*Xm)))))` para todas combinações de `mci` e `rp`, e então manter, para cada valor calculado, o menor valor entre `rp` e o valor de `bwg` obtido.

Se for esse o caso, você precisa de mais do que um simples `ifelse`, pois você tem dois vetores com comprimento > 1 para combinar. No caso, resolvi fazer um `sapply` no vetor `rp`, e então obter os valores de `bwg` para todos `mci` para cada `rp`.

Você pode também transformar o cálculo de `bwg` em uma função, para não ficar repetindo a fórmula. Por fim, usei a função `pmin` ao invés de um `ifelse`, porque fica mais elegante.

Segue o código com alguns comentários:

```
maxVal <- 30 # Mudei o nome desse valor, já existe a função max, melhor não misturar
K <- 0.0118
Xm <- 21
SD <- 0.851636356306513 
mean.b <- 28

rp <- rnorm(420, mean = mean.b, sd = SD)
mci <- seq(200, 270, 1.7)

bwg.calc <- function(maxVal, K, MCi, Xm, rp) {
  BW <- 0.0223*rp^0.8944 # Esse valor depende apenas de rp, pode ser obtido aqui
  maxVal*(1-exp(-K*(MCi-(BW*Xm))))
}       

resultado <- sapply(rp, function(i) { # Para cada rp, calculamos contra todos mci
  bwg <- bwg.calc(maxVal = maxVal, K = K, Xm = Xm, MCi = mci, rp = i)
  pmin(i, bwg) # Poderia ser ifelse(bwg > i, i, bwg)
})
```

Não vou colocar o resultado, porque é uma matriz com 42 linhas (tamanho de rp e 420 colunas (tamanho de mci):

```
> str(resultado)
 num [1:42, 1:420] 26.8 26.9 27 27 27.1 ...
```

Comment: Molx, se você poder me ajudar, você tem como me passar um email de contato? abraços!

Comment: @MARCOSSANTOS A ideia do SO é que a solução para o seu problema também sirva para ajudar outras pessoas que possam ter um problema parecido, por isso o ideal é que mantenhamos contato por aqui. Se for algo que não ficou claro ou está incorreto na resposta, pode comentar aqui. Se não for relacionado a este problema, faça uma nova pergunta. Com isso também você poderá ser ajudado por centenas de pessoas, e não só eu.

Comment: Caro Molx, você tem razão vamos tentar resolver por aqui. Contudo acho que o código não está exatamente correto pois os valores continuam estranhos, mudei a imagem para ver se fica melhor, se poder me ajudar fico grato.

Comment: @MARCOSSANTOS estranhos porque? Os valores não vão ser identicos, você utiliza `rnorm` para gerar `rp` e por isso os valores são aleatórios, cada vez que rodar o resultado vai ser um pouco diferente. Você pode testar com um conjunto padrão de dados ao invés de dados aleatórios, ou então ver o código passo a passo para entender se ele faz o que você deseja.

Comment: @MARCOSSANTOS, o cálculo pode se tornar reprodutível por meio do set.seed(). O R gera números pseudoaleatórios, logo definindo a mesma semente seria possível reproduzir exatamente os dados gerados no exemplo.